# Upholding Graph API contingent (limit) when using only the app ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook tells me that the the contingent for API calls for a certain App ID is raised when a user logs into facebook using my app.

It says that the algorithm for detecting the current limit per time is like

users (logged in?) the day before x new logins today x n

My question is: Does this only take into account new logins so that logins that occured 2 days before day x would not longer uphold my API call limit on day x+2? Or does it consider all users that ever logged in using my app?

My app only uses a facebook login once (at the beginning for law protocolling reasons) but then no more and I had to change that if user logins are counted on a 2-day basis.

Comment: _“The number of users for your app is calculated as the average number of daily active users plus today's new logins.”_

Comment: Is a login the only way to generate an "active user" or does it also count if someone uses a facebook web plugin that is associated with the app id?

Comment: No, that does not count as an app user.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will implement a daily login.